# Icon before the shipping method label in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]I'm trying to get an SVG icon before each shipping method (local pickup and free shipping) in WooCommerce. So far i have been struggling with :before pseudo element, but without avail. See screenshot for example.

Here is the code i've tried. It actually works, but the icon is appears after the shipping method name. I know it has something to do with the priorities, but i can't figure out how.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 
'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, 
$method ) {     

if( $method->method_id == "free_shipping:1" ) {
$label = $label.'<img class="free_shipping_icon' src='/content/icon.svg'>";

} 
else if( $method->method_id == "local_pickup:6" ) {
$label = $label."<img class='local_pickup_icon' src='/content/icon.svg'>";       
}
return $label; 
}
```

Comment: You should provide your code attempt in your question, as nearly nobody will help you actually.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, i forgot. I added my attempted code.